# Image upload with React Native and Nodejs Express Multer

Tags: node.js, express, react-native, image-uploading, multer

I have a Nodejs with Express server running on local that allow me to upload images, I did it with no problems on Postman, but when i tried to upload from React Native, the server get the request data, including the image, but do not upload it to server! What am i doing wrong here, please take a look!

here is my multer config:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './server/uploads/');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
})

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
}

const upload = multer({ 
  storage: storage, 
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});
```

here is my routes call:

```
route.post('/products', upload.single('image'), userAuthenticate, ProductController.createProduct);
```

here is my controller:

```
export const createProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req);

    const { serial, name, description, cate_id, quantity, origin_price, sell_price, attributes } = req.body;
    const newProduct = new Product({ serial, name, description, cate_id, quantity, origin_price, sell_price, attributes });

    newProduct._creator = req.user._id;

    // upload image  
    console.log(req.file);
    newProduct.image = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);

    let product = await newProduct.save();
    let user = req.user;
    user._products.push(product);
    await user.save();
    return res.status(201).json({ product });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    return res.status(e.status || 404).json({ err: true, message: e.message });
  }
}
```

and here is my post request from react native:

```
const data = new FormData();
    data.append('serial', serial);
    data.append('name', name);
    data.append('description', description);
    data.append('sell_price', [{ 'value': sell_price }]);
    data.append('origin_price', origin_price);
    data.append('quantity', quantity);
    data.append('cate_id', cate_id);
    data.append('attr', attr);
    data.append('image', {
      uri: image.uri,
      type: image.type,
      name: image.name
    });

    let product = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/products',
      data: data,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 
        'x-auth': token, 
      }
    })
```

And here is my image field in Product model:

```
image: {
    type: Buffer
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same problem, because there is an open issue [See here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25790) on react native.

But I found a nice solution using [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#user-content-multipartform-data-example--post-form-data-with-file-and-data)

as you may see in the documentation, you can implement the following:

```
upload = async () => {
    let ret = await RNFetchBlob.fetch(
      'POST',
      'http://localhost:3000/api/products',
      {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'x-auth': token, 
      },
      [
        {
          name: 'image',
          filename: Date.now() + '.png',
          type: 'image/png',
          data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(image.uri),
        },
      ],
    );
    return ret;
  };
```

As you see, there is an array, where you can add the objects you want to upload, just like in the FormData.